# Godot export crash

Tags: windows, game-development, godot, gdscript

I am new to godot engine and have started working on a project(i am using gdscript)...
When I run the project as test it works fine(like in the godot engine), but when I export it, it shows the godot logo and then crashes...
**This is my godot file system**
[godot file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of9Fe.png)

**This is the message i am getting in the debug console**
[error message in debug menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvhSA.png)

```
 platform/windows/os_windows.cpp:2905 - Condition "ret == 0" is true. Returned: ERR_CANT_FORK
```

Please help I have worked hard on this project and if I cant export all that is for nothing

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to transcribe the error image you linked for you:

> platform/windows/os_windows_cpp:2905 - Condition "ret == 0" is true. Returned: ERR_CANT_FORK
>
> editor/editor_export.h:251 - Resources Modification: Could not start rcedit executable. Configure rcedit path in the Editor Settings (Export -> Windows -> Rcedit)

Emphasis:

> Configure rcedit path in the Editor Settings (Export -> Windows -> Rcedit)

*ERR_CANT_FORK means it could not <strike>[fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call))</strike> start a new process. Which process?*

> Could not start rcedit executable

If we search Rcedit on Godot's official documentation the following article shows up: [Changing application icon for Windows](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/export/changing_application_icon_for_windows.html). It says:

> Before selecting it in the export options, you will need to install an extra tool called rcedit. You can download it [here](https://github.com/electron/rcedit/releases).
>
> After downloading, you need to tell Godot the path to the rcedit executable on your computer. Go to Editor → Editor Settings → Export → Windows. Click on the folder icon for the rcedit entry. Navigate to and select the rcedit executable.

To reiterate: **Configure Rcedit**.